# Search option in GridView without the need for Search Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have a grid that displays data I need a search filter that filters automatically when we type. There is no need for the Search button. I have tried some JS code I found but doesn't seem to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/ASPSnippets_Pager.min.js"></script>
<script src="ASPSnippets_Pager.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
            GetStores(1);
        });
        $("[id*=txtSearch]").live("keyup", function () {
            GetStores(parseInt(1));
        });
        $(".Pager .page").live("click", function () {
            GetStores(parseInt($(this).attr('page')));
        });
        function SearchTerm() {
            return jQuery.trim($("[id*=txtSearch]").val());
        };
        function GetStores(pageIndex) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/GetStores",
                data: '{searchTerm: "' + SearchTerm() + '", pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
        var row;
        function OnSuccess(response) {
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
            var xml = $(xmlDoc);
            var Stores = xml.find("Stores");
            if (row == null) {
                row = $("[id*=GridView1] tr:last-child").clone(true);
            }
            $("[id*=GridView1] tr").not($("[id*=GridView1] tr:first-child")).remove();
            if (Stores.length > 0) {
                $.each(Stores, function () {
                    var customer = $(this);
                    $("td", row).eq(0).html($(this).find("<%# Eval("zone") %>").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(1).html($(this).find("<%# Eval("displayName") %>").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(0).html($(this).find("StoreName").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(1).html($(this).find("ZoneName").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(0).html($(this).find("StoreNames").text());
                    $("td", row).eq(1).html($(this).find("ZoneNames").text());
                    $("[id*=GridView1]").append(row);
                    row = $("[id*=GridView1] tr:last-child").clone(true);
                });
                var pager = xml.find("Pager");
                $(".Pager").ASPSnippets_Pager({
                    ActiveCssClass: "current",
                    PagerCssClass: "pager",
                    PageIndex: parseInt(pager.find("PageIndex").text()),
                    PageSize: parseInt(pager.find("PageSize").text()),
                    RecordCount: parseInt(pager.find("RecordCount").text())
                });

                $(".ContactName").each(function () {
                    var searchPattern = new RegExp('(' + SearchTerm() + ')', 'ig');
                    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(searchPattern, "<span class = 'highlight'>" + SearchTerm() + "</span>"));
                });
            } else {
                var empty_row = row.clone(true);
                $("td:first-child", empty_row).attr("colspan", $("td", row).length);
                $("td:first-child", empty_row).attr("align", "center");
                $("td:first-child", empty_row).html("No records found for the search criteria.");
                $("td", empty_row).not($("td:first-child", empty_row)).remove();
                $("[id*=GridView1]").append(empty_row);
            }
        };
</script>
```

I tried this but the page keeps on loading doesn't seem to stop. I am looking for an alternative.

Comment: check your console in case of any errors..  put a debug on `success` function check your debug hit on `Default.aspx/GetStores` `web method` what response you get in `response.d` ?

Comment: I am actually looking for an alternative i dont want to use this code because i dont understand it ... and i tried but the debug wont go in the debug point

Comment: @Curiousdev do u know anyother method to do this? search option in the gridview without search button??

Comment: you can use [jquery datatable](https://datatables.net/examples/) or [jqgrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) or many other options but still it use jquery so u have to stick with jquery to achieve this

Comment: ya think i would have to thank you :)

Comment: you're welcome i think your code is pretty well just you need to find out what's going wrong in there...

Comment: ya i know i thought there be a easier way np ill try to find out whats wrong with it

Comment: lemme know if u'll stuck anywhere i'll help u

Comment: ok thak you:))))